# How to post the form selected when inside a foreach

Tags: javascript

I have some data that I need users to pick from.  The values are wrapped up in a forEach with a form that posts the selected list item.

```
<ul id="results">
  <% records.forEach(function(value) { %>
        <li>
            <form id="detailsForm" action="/search/detail" method="post">
               <div>
                    Employee Id: <%= value.netId %>
                    Name: <%= value.FirstName%> <%= value.LastName %>
                </div>
            </form>
        </li>
        <% }); %>
    </ul>
```

The javascript is simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#results").on('click', 'li', function () {
        document.getElementById("detailsForm").submit();

    });
</script>
```

The problem is that no matter which record is chosen, the first result is always the one passed in the post.  That makes sense since the form names are the same in the forEach.

```
document.getElementById("detailsForm").submit();
```

I need a better way to post only the list item that is clicked on.  I thought about doing it differently and trying to get $(this).text(), but there is a ton of whitespace and carriage returns (not shown for clarity) and I really need to serialize the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could imagine that your problem is using an `id` in a loop. Remember that `id` must be unique on the page! The generated HTML will probably include several forms with the same id, so with JavaScript `getElementById` you will always get the first one

EDIT:
So remove the id of the form element.
And change the JavaScript like that:

```
$("#results").on('click', 'form', function () {
        $(this).submit();
});
```

Comment: Yes, agreed.   However, I can certainly get the actual text of the selected listitem using $(this).text(), so I assumed that there was a way to select the form as well.  Perhaps there is a different approach where I don't use a form within a loop?  This starts to veer way off topic quickly...

Comment: The form in a loop - meaning several forms on a page is no problem. You had just to find a way how to select a form unique. With your first approach you could of course retrieve the text via $(this).text() but with document.getElementById you always searched in the DOM again from top to bottom for the form and not within the clicked element - which is the reason only the first form was found. Hope this explanation helps!